# Whom I am teaching?

Tags: possessives, relative-pronouns, present-continuous, who-whom

Is "whom" in that sentence correct?

> She's a mother of one of my students whom I am teaching on Skype

Comment: Which sentence are you asking about? The one in your title? Or the one in your question? Also, what do you think might be wrong with sentence? Questions that only ask "Is this correct?" without explaining anything else are typically closed as proofreading requests.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct, although most speakers would shorten **I am** to **I'm**.

To be sure, break the sentence into its two main parts.

1. *She is the mother of one of my students*
2. *I am teaching this student on Skype*.

**This student** is the object of the second sentence.
So the relative pronoun required is **whom** rather than **who**.

You might simplify you sentence as:

> She is the mother of a student whom I teach.

However, your sentence raises several questions.

The first is whether the average English speaker would use the more formal **whom** (which is steadily losing ground among native English speakers) in the place of the more common **who**.

The second is whether you are teaching the *mother* or her child. The sentence does not make this clear.

Thirdly, she is **the** mother, not **a** mother of the student,

And finally you are probably teaching the student **via** or **through** Skype rather than **on** it.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043658/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/who-or-whom)

Comment: Your point about *I am / I'm* is a bit superfluous here. Sure it is often abbreviated in speech, but enunciating "whom I'm" is trickier. If we are trying to make the sentence more casual then it works *without* either who *or* whom. I think if anyone is so formal as to vocalise "whom" would continue to say "I am".

Comment: @Astralbee Strangely, speaking as a long-standing *whomer*, I found *whom I'm* rather easier to deal with than *whom I am*. But this is the freedom that language gives us.

Comment: +1 for calling out the possible ambiguity of it being the mother or the child who's being taught. (It would be quite a stretch to assume that *your* student is the mother of a student child, and the sentence construction implies otherwise, but it's still possible to take it the wrong way.)

Answer (score 2):

*Whom* is correct in this sentence. You use "whom" when referring to the object of the verb.

> She's a mother of one of my students whom I am teaching on Skype.

The classic test is to see if the verb works with "he/she" or "him/her".

In this case the verb is *teaching*, and you would say "teaching *him*", **not** "teaching *he*". This confirms that it is the *object of the verb*, and "whom" is correct.

However the sentence would be better as:

> She's **the** mother of one of my students whom I am teaching on Skype.

(unless you deliberately meant to imply the student has two moms, which is possible these days)